# Unity3d crashes every time I run my game because of the spawner Game object spawning Enemy prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crash

I am about half way done with the firs prototype of my new game-idea, and I am  tring to implement a spawner that randomly spawns one of 3 enemy prefabs. This enemy spawning hasn't been working very well for me, as I have always found little problems here and there. One of these problems was major and caused Unity to crash every time I pressed Play ind the editor. I wasn't sure what the problem was, and so I Build the game I tried running the build, and it crashed as well. Then eventually I scraped my spawner and tried a new one. This one also crashed Unity every time, so I tried to spawn a random sphere with no components to it, and this seems to be working perfectly fine.

While running the game In the Unity Editor, I simultaneously open the task manager to see what was going on. It told me Unity was running like a charm, although it used about 1.5 gigs of Ram. Is it a lot? TBH, I don't know if that's the reason it keeps crashing, but I wouldn't know why it takes these amounts of ram. As soon as I deactivated the spawner it stopped crashing, so is it the spawner? I personally don't think so because I was able to spawn the sphere without the game crashing, but as soon as I try to spawn the enemies breaks down.

-> edit: The game doesn't really crash, it just starts loading into infinity, forcing me to end the application and reopen it hands why I am not able to provide any error codes.

Here is the spawner script I used:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] enemyPrefabs; 
    public float spawnRate = 1.0f; //The frequency at which enemies spawn.
    private float nextSpawn = 0.0f; //used to trigger the next spawn

    void Update()
    {
        //Make enemy spawn on a countdown timer
        if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
        {
            nextSpawn = Time.time + spawnRate; // Trigger next spawn
            Debug.Log("Spawn");
            //Spawn the enemy in the same place as the spawner
            GameObject piClone = Instantiate(enemyPrefabs[Random.Range(0, enemyPrefabs.Length)], transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: `... as GameObject` seems idempotent to me, as you are already catching the return type as a GameObject.

Comment: Does the `enemyPrefab` happen to have the Spawner script attached by chance? Because nothing seems out of the ordinary for this script.